# Is setting of non-optional ivars demanded in all init methods?

Tags: initialization, sprite-kit, swift, subclassing

I'm trying to create an `SKSpriteNode` subclass. The plan was to let this handle most of the setup internally but annoyingly this seems to enforce quite a bit of code-duplication, in particular when setting up non-optional ivars and constants.

```
class TrollSpriteRegular : SKSpriteNode{
    let head : SKSpriteNode
    let body : SKSpriteNode

    init(){
        head = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.orangeColor(), size: CGSizeMake(60, 60))
        body = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.purpleColor(), size: CGSizeMake(40, 60))
        super.init()
    }

    // Desginated intiallizer
    init(texture: SKTexture!, color: UIColor!, size: CGSize) {
        head = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.orangeColor(), size: CGSizeMake(60, 60))
        body = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.purpleColor(), size: CGSizeMake(40, 60))
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
    }
}
```

If I try to remove the creation of head or body from either one of the two initializers this results in a compiler error and I am unable to build. Is there any way to avoid this, or is perhaps the above patter not particularly swift-friendly?

I "need" the init method to allow creating new instances simply by using `let trollSprite = TrollSpriteRegular()`.

---

Edit: OK the above can be simplified by defining the constants when they're declared.

```
class TrollSpriteRegular : SKSpriteNode{
    let head = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.orangeColor(), size: CGSizeMake(60, 60))
    let body = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.purpleColor(), size: CGSizeMake(40, 60))
...
```

If however I add a variable that should actually receive its value by an init-method I will have the same problem. e.g.:

```
let trollName : String

init(name :String){ 
    trollName = name
    super.init(texture: nil, color: nil, size: CGSizeZero)
}
```

This will force me to define trollName both in my own `init(name:)` and in the designated initializer. Oh, well.

Comment: What is the designated init of SKSpriteNode? You should only be calling the designated initializer of the super class I believe

Comment: The designated initializer is `init(texture:color:size)`but it is not particularly suitable for my subclass. It seems unnecessary messy to have to call `let troll = TrollSpriteRegular(texture: nil, color: nil, size: CGSizeZero)` when I could have gotten away with `et trollSprite = TrollSpriteRegular()` But if that is the way to tango I guess I have to yield...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A designated initializer is required to initialize all of the class's state. In a convenience initializer, you can just delegate that responsibility to a designated initializer.

However, in your case it looks like you want two designated initializers. But since these variables don't depend on any input into the initializer for their value, you can just define their value in their declaration. Here's the less repetitive version of that class:

```
class TrollSpriteRegular : SKSpriteNode {
    let head : SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.orangeColor(), size: CGSizeMake(60, 60))
    let body : SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.purpleColor(), size: CGSizeMake(40, 60))
}
```

Comment: It still seems clunky though, if I want to add other (property-like) ivars created through their own initializers I _have_ to define their values in both the designated initializer and my own, right?

Comment: @nickfalk: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Any value you want to create that doesn't depend on input an initializer can be defined this way. If it does depend on input to an initializer, then all designated initializers must define it — but it isn't normal to need many designated initializers. A lot of the time you can just write one and make the others convenience initializers.

Comment: Hm, I think I might be missing something then: When I subclass SKSpriteNode I have to _include_ the designated initializer from the parent class, even if this has no parameters for the required variables. When it is included it is required to set the variables for the app to compile.

Comment: What about for classes loaded from the Storyboard, (e.g. VCs)? Is it good practice to override the designated init and set the additional ivars?

Comment: @HariKaramSingh: Outlets are always optional, specifically because it isn't practical to worry about them in your initializer.

Comment: What about instance vars?  It seems odd to me to require !'s everywhere for these optional params. Am I missing something?

Comment: @HariKaramSingh: [It doesn't require `!`s everywhere](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH5-XID_58).

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is to be expected considering non optional variable can not be nil. If you're looking for a way to do all this more concisely, you can do the initialization of your variables inline using default values (colors and size). Then if you happen to have an initializer that needs to change one of these values, you could change the value of the sprite's color or size properties directly.

```
class TrollSpriteRegular: SKSpriteNode {
    let head = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.orangeColor(), size: CGSizeMake(60.0, 60.0))
    let body = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.purpleColor(), size: CGSizeMake(40.0, 60.0))

    ...
}
```